# Missing double authentication with User Models in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

I want to make my first student's project in Django and I am trying to make a management system that has two authentications from one site.
I want to have a staff sign-up form and a customer sign-up form if it's possible.
I made one AppBaseUser Model, which inherits AbstractUser, and two other models - one for customers, and one for staff, witch will I make it in forms in the template. They inherit AppBaseUser and extend it.
Everything is working, but I don't have a double password authentication and the password is in plain text not in a hash in DB.

class AppBaseUser(AbstractUser):
MIN_LEN_FIRST_NAME = 2
MAX_LEN_FIRST_NAME = 40

```
MIN_LEN_LAST_NAME = 2
MAX_LEN_LAST_NAME = 40

first_name = models.CharField(
    max_length=MAX_LEN_FIRST_NAME,
    null=False,
    blank=False,
    validators=[
        validators.MinLengthValidator(MIN_LEN_FIRST_NAME),
        validate_only_letters,
    ]
)

last_name = models.CharField(
    max_length=MAX_LEN_LAST_NAME,
    null=False,
    blank=False,
    validators=[
        validators.MinLengthValidator(MIN_LEN_LAST_NAME),
        validate_only_letters,
    ]
)

email = models.EmailField(
    unique=True,
    null=False,
    blank=False,
)
```

class AppCustomerUser(AppBaseUser):
MAX_LEN_PHONE_NUMBER = len('+359-888-88-88-88')
MIN_LEN_PHONE_NUMBER = len('+359888888888')

```
# TODO Make it with enumerate!
GENDER_CHOICES = [('Male', 'Male'), ('Female', 'Female'), ('Do not show', 'Do not show'),]
MAX_LEN_GENDER = len('Do not show')

HAIR_TYPES_CHOICES = [
    ('Straight hair', 'Straight hair'),
    ('Wavy hair', 'Wavy hair'),
    ('Curly hair', 'Curly hair'),
    ('Kinky hair', 'Kinky hair'),
    ('I am not sure', 'I am not sure'),
]
MAX_LEN_HAIR_TYPES = len('I am not sure')

HAIR_LONG_CHOICES = [
    ('Short hair', 'Short hair'),
    ('Middle hair', 'Middle hair'),
    ('Long hair', 'Long hair'),
    ('Very long hair', 'Very long hair'),
    ('I am not sure', 'I am not sure'),
]
MAX_LEN_HAIR_LONG = len('Very long hair')

MAX_LEN_FURTHER_EXPLANATION = 250

phone_number = models.CharField(
    max_length=MAX_LEN_PHONE_NUMBER,
    validators=[validators.MinLengthValidator(MIN_LEN_PHONE_NUMBER),],
    null=False,
    blank=False,
)

gender = models.CharField(
    max_length=MAX_LEN_GENDER,
    choices=GENDER_CHOICES,
)

hair_type = models.CharField(
    max_length=MAX_LEN_HAIR_TYPES,
    choices=HAIR_TYPES_CHOICES,
)

hair_long = models.CharField(
    max_length=MAX_LEN_HAIR_LONG,
    choices=HAIR_LONG_CHOICES,
)

further_explanation = models.TextField(
    max_length=MAX_LEN_FURTHER_EXPLANATION,
    null=True,
    blank=True,
)

# USERNAME_FIELD = "email"

is_staff = False
is_superuser = False

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.get_full_name()} - {self.pk}'
```

class AppStaffUser(AppBaseUser):
is_staff = True
is_superuser = False

```
MAX_LEN_POSITION = 100

position = models.CharField(
    max_length=MAX_LEN_POSITION,
    null=False,
    blank=False,
)
```

I have in settings.py ---->

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.AppBaseUser'

I try to change settings, and try to inherit AbstractBaseUser but with no result.